# Display description text on focus on inputs

Tags: jquery, input

I am trying to add a description text to each input field, that is only visible when the field is in focus, and then description will be hidden on blur.

But when a input field is focused, it shows all the descriptions to all the input fields.

Hope somebody can help.

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/serddk/6g5w2/1/

```
jQuery('li > .gfield_description').hide();

jQuery('li > .ginput_container > input').each( function() {
    jQuery(this).focus( function() {
        jQuery('li > .gfield_description').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    jQuery(this).blur( function() {
        jQuery('li > .gfield_description').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: it is because of ``'li > .gfield_description'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li > .gfield_description` is corresponding to all description, you need to use `this` to refer the related description only.

Do like this:

```
jQuery('li > .gfield_description').hide();

jQuery('li > .ginput_container > input').each( function() {
    jQuery(this).focus( function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
    });
    jQuery(this).blur( function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().next().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6g5w2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(this).parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/6g5w2/3/

try this:

```
jQuery('li > .ginput_container > input').each( function() {
  jQuery(this).focus( function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('div').next('div').fadeIn('slow');
  });
  jQuery(this).blur( function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('div').next('div').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

you are having the bug, because you are targeting this way: `li > .gfield_description` which hits ALL elements with this class.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are currently wrong, but also you can cut your code right down and you don't need to use `each` to loop through the inputs:

http://jsfiddle.net/6g5w2/4/

This code will do exactly what you are after but is far more efficient as it doesn't iterate using `each`:

```
jQuery('li > .ginput_container > input')
.on("focus", function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().next().fadeIn('slow');    
}).on("blur", function() {    
    jQuery(this).parent().next().fadeOut();
});
```

I've also replaced this line: `jQuery('li > .gfield_description').hide();` which can be set initially with `CSS` giving you a further performance saving.